# SwiftUI embed youtube -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, swiftui, youtube, swift5, ios14

I'm trying to embed an youtube video in swiftUI app (building for iOS 14)

i'm using CocoaPods with the following Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'TestProjectYoutube' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestProjectYoutube
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
pod 'URLImage'
pod 'Introspect'

end
```

I've created the following view

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
     
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack() {
            VideoView(videoID: "CX-BdDHW0Ho")
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct VideoView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let videoID: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.1, height: 0.1))
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let youtubeURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)") else { return }
        uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        uiView.load(URLRequest(url: youtubeURL))
    }
}
```

The error i got is:

```
2023-01-16 15:35:16.130698+0100 app[44720:3273388] -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2824115c0
2023-01-16 15:35:16.130920+0100 app[44720:3273388] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2824115c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18048bc80 0x197cb1ee4 0x18055c708 0x18042556c 0x18042477c 0x18ac78644 0x18e74ce50 0x18e9d0ca4 0x18e9d0888 0x18e94c418 0x18e963de0 0x18ecdd224 0x18ecdcec8 0x18e72b69c 0x18e727c4c 0x18e72cd18 0x18ac73590 0x18ac7410c 0x1804ac468 0x1804bc598 0x1803fe774 0x180403e48 0x180417194 0x1a0f56988 0x182c1aa88 0x1829b3fc8 0x187c6cd68 0x187bb783c 0x187b9d1dc 0x10281f3fc 0x10281f530 0x102ff84d0)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2824115c0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

When I replace the youtube.com with google.com, i dont get the error and google is loaded.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: _"When I replace the youtube.com with google.com"_. What do you mean by this? Can you show exactly the code that isn't working?

Comment: It uses an WKWebView to show en embed url from youtube, that dont work.

when i replace this url with some google url, it works. Seems that the code is valid but somehow youtube is not working. Tried it with vimeo and also dont work

Comment: You need to include a stack trace of the crash in your question. What is throwing that exception?

Comment: i will update the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but where is the problem? The code you've supplied does not give the error you've shown. Please give a minimal example that reproduces the problem, ideally for SwiftUI as `struct ContentView` people can paste into Xcode and run. Take a look at [mcve]

Comment: Again, thanks for the update, but the latest code you've supplied works fine running on iOS 14 simulator (build with Xcode 14.2). If you start a new project with only that code, do you see the errors you've listed?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i started a new project and it works just fine.
I've switched to CocoaPods and then the error occurs. 

I have added my Podfile now.

Comment: So try adding your podfile to your new project, adding the pods one at a time, until you find the one that makes it crash. I'm pretty sure that most of these pods are superfluous these days though!

Comment: After a lot of try and error, removed almost every single line of code in my project. It will not build.

Till i found the setting to generate an plist file, i'm using an custom plist file and that is the issue. Try to debug this one now.